# Checking if jQuery variable is referring to a specific DOM element

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/vq062uhk/

```
var $currentRow = null;

$(function() {

    $('.set').click(function() {
        $currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    });

    $('.check').click(function() {
        console.dir($(this).closest('tr'));

        if ($currentRow == $(this).closest('tr')) {
            alert('Yes');
        }
        else {
            alert('No');
        }
    });
});
```

I have a table and a variable called $currentRow which refers to the current tr element. I want to be able to check if an item (in this case a button "Is Current?") is in the current row.

I could give the tr's unique id's or attributes but I'm wondering if I can avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code,

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    console.dir($(this).closest('tr'));
    if ($currentRow && $currentRow.is($(this).closest('tr'))) {
        alert('Yes');
    }
    else {
        alert('No');
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vq062uhk/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) like

```
$currentRow.is($(this).closest('tr'))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/czjaetpq/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vq062uhk/2/

```
var $currentRow = null;

$(function(){
    $('.set').click(function(){        
        $currentRow = $(this).parents('tr');
    });

    $('.check').click(function(){
        if ( $currentRow[0] == $(this).parents('tr')[0] ) {
            alert('Yes');
        }
        else {
            alert('No');
        }
    });
});
```